# Replacing string in a file with script

Tags: text-processing, sed

One of the ways replacing a string with `sed` can be done as follows:

```
sed -i 's/old_str/new_str/' file.txt
```

However if `replace.sh` is

```
 sed -i 's/$1/$2/' $3
```

the command `./replace.sh old_str new_str file.txt` doesn't seem to work -- after making `replace.sh` executable of course. Why is that?

---

I am aware `rpl` does exactly the same as I intend to do with `replace.sh`, but I'd like to understand why is it not working.

Comment: You're hitting a quoting issue.  The single quote `'` character prevents `$1` from being expanded and you have the literal string `$1`.   If you use `"`" instead then it'll work... but beware of magic characters in a solution like this;  `./replace.sh my/string new/stuff myfile` won't work!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fend off the issue regarding magic characters? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter expansion inside single quotes (see [this previous answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash))

```bsh
toto=1
echo '$toto'
> $toto
echo "$toto"
> 1
```

Simply replace your single quotes with double quotes and your script will do what you expect.